# Error Install ubuntu on lenovo notebook g510

Tags: ati, video, 14.04

I'm tried to install ubuntu desktop 14.04 on my notebook lenovo g510 (AMD radeon HD8570) but after installation finished when OS starting display following massagge: The system is running in low-graphics mode.
Could someone please help me to solve this problem?
Thank's in advance
Maurizio

Comment: Try open Ubuntu from CD-ROM then install Ubuntu thru that window GUI. My laptop was Lenovo Ideapad G500 and meet same issues before. But, My HD 8570/2g still not working until now. The existing VGA controller was Intel and I can see window without problem I'm still search solution for AMD HD 8570....

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the solution suggested at [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/141607#218095)
Looks like your graphics driver was not installed (correctly). Try to re-install the driver as suggested in the linked post.

Comment: Yes I did it but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the logfiles (/var/log/Xorg.0.log or /var/log/gdm/* or /var/log/lightdm/* or syslog)?

Comment: Yes I think ther is an error in x-0.log under /var/log/lightdm/.

Comment: Yes I think ther is an error in x-0.log under /var/log/lightdm/. now I put the log files in my web server and send you a link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2nw0ZlDPDzcYk9LVUVQaFNCaTBmOG1oMHd4d2FyQ1lXeS1R/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here the link to download the log files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2nw0ZlDPDzcYk9LVUVQaFNCaTBmOG1oMHd4d2FyQ1lXeS1R/edit?usp=sharing